# Why i can't access my variable declared in package from sub declared in the same package in Perl?

Tags: perl, package

I don't understand why can't access variable `$var` in sub `mysub`. Both packages are defined in the same file exactly as in this example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

Util::mysub();

package Util;

use warnings;
use strict;

my $var = 'i have a value!';

# prints 'var in package: i have a value!'
print "var in package: $var\n";

sub mysub {
    # generates warning 'Use of uninitialized value $var...'
    print "var in sub: $var\n";
}

1;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call `Util::mysub()` several lines prior to assigning to the file scoped `$var`.

If your package were in a seperate file, the `use` statement and its implied `BEGIN` block would give the assignment priority. Alternatively, you could put the package definition first or use your own `BEGIN` block.

Comment: packages are in same file exactly as example

Comment: @lemur I see that.  I was simply suggesting fixes.

Comment: There is no `$Util::var`.  Lexical variables do not belong to any package.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the variable inside your sub, it just hasn't been set yet.

`my` has both compile-time and run-time behavior. At compile-time it declares a variable name for the remainder of the enclosing scope, thus making `use strict` happy. Initialization happens at run-time *when control flow reaches the declaration*. Because your call to `mysub()` happens before control flow reaches the `my $var = ...`, the value of `$var` seen in `mysub` is `undef` and perl emits a "Use of uninitialized value..." warning. If you called your sub *after* the `my $var = ...` it would be defined and you'd see that value instead (and no warning).